# How to redeploy EAR file to Web-Logic without restart server?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I have EAR file (which includes a WAR file and EJB jar file) was deployed on Web-Logic(10.3.6) successful.

Now, I have updated EAR file and I redeploy again follow steps: delete old files on the server and install new EAR file without restart server. Every file have been deployed in Active state. But I got some exception related EJB injection. Then I restart Web-logic, my app is running fine.

What's wrong with the redeploy way?

Thanks in advance for any Help...

Comment: By "delete old files" you mean undeploy the previous version of the application using WLS console?

Comment: Yes, I undeployed the previous version by deleting EAR file using WLS console

Answer (score 2):

Weblogic has an lots of documentation about this topic. Sometimes it's referred to as a "hot deploy" or an "in-place" deploy. In the weblogic admin console there is an option to `update` an ear file rather than what you are doing with the delete->redeploy method.

Just make sure to update your `Weblogic-Application-Version` property in the `MANIFEST.MF` of your ear so that weblogic knows it's a new version. Here are some useful links:

[Oracle redeploy documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13702/redeploy.htm#i1025590)

[An older but still valid list of steps to hot deploy](http://yogendrakrsingh.blogspot.com/2010/03/steps-to-configure-hot-deployment-from.html)

That said - the problem you are seeing may be something different and your question will need to be updated with more details if the Oracle docs don't help.