# hot deployment of tomcat project in weblogic?

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, weblogic

i have tomcat project the directory structure is

[image]

previously i was using tomcat server, whenever i modified .java files i used to build the project and restarted the server in eclipse through plugin than the changes would have taken effect.

[image]

Now in my company they changed from tomcat to weblogic since i am new to it, i used to build war file every time and deploy manually to check the changes.
Can any one tell me how to do hot deployment in web logic. i googled it but it says i need to change project type to dynamic project, that i cant do since it already in development.

is their better way just make changes to java file build and no need to restart the server through eclipse in weblogic 12c. 
Eclipse IDE luna
weblogic 12c server
project type : tomcat project structure

Comment: "that i cant do since it already in development", no, you can! the "Dynamic Web Project" in eclipse is very flexible. even with your file structure, you can make mappings between your files to the standard war structure with the "Deployment Assembly" preference page of your project.

Comment: And you can turn your current project into a "Dynamic Web Project" by right click on your project, and "Configure"-->"Turn Into Faceted from..."-->check "Dynamic Web Module" facet and it's version you want, also "Java" facet and it's version.

Comment: Also note that you can use weblogic server at development time, but you need to install the server adapter plugin for it.

Comment: i am not allowed to change the project type. i think through ant script it can be achieved.

Comment: See the answer here about hot deploys: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525685/how-to-redeploy-ear-file-to-web-logic-without-restart-server/26534532#26534532 You can hot deploy a war using the `update` command in the admin console or calling `welogic.deployer` with the update option: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs91/deployment/wldeployer.html#1008424 You can call `weblogic.deployer` from ant if you want

Answer (score 2):

I think how you doing that is a little old fashioned. With eclipse luna, tomcat 5.0 - tomcat 8.0 is well supported. And take some effort to turn your project into a 'Dynamic Web Project', in that way you will benifit a lot from the experience of other people.

For hot redeploying, you can try [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/), it reload your changed java class without reloading the whole applcaition.But it's a commercial software, and I don't know a good and free alternative yet.

Comment: with out jrebel cant i do with weblogic.

Comment: Without JRebel, you're limited to whatever HotSwap will do for you in debug mode in your IDE or hot deployment, so you'd get OutOfMemory errors because the classloaders will leak.